# IBM Cloud Object Storage HMAC Credentials

Tags: object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

In following along with https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/iam/service-credentials.html#service-credentials I have tried multiple times to create my HMAC creadentials for usage in my application, however the credentials created do not contain cos_hmac_keys.

This should be simple enough, I added 

`{"HMAC":true}`

to the inline JSON config for my credential creation, but still am having no luck. Any insight here would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a same issue and here's my suggestion.
I'm wondering if your object-storage instance is newly-created or created long time ago.If it's old, then why don't you try to create a new one , as, in my case, I failed in my old instance and successfully created in my newly-created instance.( Each has a little bit different UI/Looks/ICons[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf95t.png)

Comment: Yea, essentially I had an older version that didn't allow HMAC credentials. Apparently there are different types of 'Object Storage' underlying the platform.